# InfluxdB Flux Query Measurements That Contain a Substring

Tags: influxdb

I am using InfluxDB's Flux query language to filter by measurement names. I want to know if it is possible to query for a measurement that contains a substring? For example if I have the measurement name “**foo_bar**” can I use a filter to look for any measurement that has substring “**bar**”? I tried the below and it did not work. Alternatively I can use regex but want to know if this function should work?

```
|> filter(fn: (r) => strings.containsStr(v: r._measurement, substr: "bar")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
|> filter(fn: (r) => strings.containsStr(v: r._measurement, substr: "bar") == true)
```

Comment: I'd like to add that `import "strings"` is required before using the strings module. Also the part ` == true` might be obsolete. See https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/strings/hasprefix/ for the documentation.